# Javascript Object Array Sorting Issue

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript array of objects to sort and arrange it as a new object array preserving the order.

My array of objects. I get them ordered in the way that I want. The index of the objects are 0,1 & 2 in this.

```
[{0: {name: 'Joel', age:25, id: 2}}, {1: {name: 'Sam', age: 23, id: 4}}, {2: {name: 'Tim', age:27, id: 3}}]
```

What I want is to make 'id' the index value. And I want it in ascending order of the 'name' (Preserving the above order)

```
[{2: {name: 'Joel', age:25, id: 2}}, {4: {name: 'Sam', age: 23, id: 4}}, {3: {name: 'Tim', age:27, id: 3}}]
```

I tried using this function.

```
for (i in members) {
    member[members[i].id] = members[i];
}
```

But it failed. The output was

```
[{}, {}, {name: "Joel", age:25, id: 2}, {name: "Tim", age:27, id: 3}, {name: "Sam", age: 23, id: 4}]
```

I tried using forEach and sort methods too. But all failed.

Is there any way to accomplish this in JavaScript.

Comment: `[2: {name: Joel,...` is invalid syntax. Arrays do not have key-value pairs. Also, strings need delimiters.

Comment: @tha07 you're previous desired output and current output is different. which one you want to have ?

Comment: I want the failed output to be ordered by the  name attribute.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the situation. Code Maniac's answer is correct. My edit to the array was wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with help of [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```js
let obj = [{0: {name: 'Joel', age:25, id: 2}}, {1: {name: 'Sam', age: 23, id: 4}}, {2: {name: 'Tim', age:27, id: 3}}]


let op = obj.map((e,index)=>{
  return{
    [e[index].id] : e[index]
  }
}).sort((a,b)=> Object.keys(a) - Object.keys(b))

console.log(op)
```

Comment: I corrected my array. is this code still okay to the question.

Comment: @tha07 yeah. i added this answer by removing your syntax errors only. otherwise it won't even run

Comment: sorry for the situation. I misunderstood it. Thank you for your help :)